# killing screen session not respond

Tags: display

I have a screen session on a server. I lost wireless connection. When reconnecting to the server, the screen session is shown as "Attached" in "screen -ls". I cannot detach it by "screen -d session#" however, neither can I kill it by "screen -X -S session# quit". How can I deal with it?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brute-force way of doing it is:

```
ps waux | grep screen
```

Find the pid and then do a `kill -9` on it...
Otherwise, try these command-line arguments to [screen](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/screen-3.9.4/html_chapter/screen_3.html#SEC3):

> -D [pid.sessionname]
>       Do not start screen, but instead detach a screen session running
>   elsewhere (see section 8.1 Detach).
>   '-d' has the same effect as typing C-a
>   d from the controlling terminal for
>   the session. '-D' is the equivalent to
>   the power detach key. If no session
>   can be detached, this option is
>   ignored. In combination with the -r/-R
>   option more powerful effects can be
>   achieved:

```
-d -r
    Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first. 
-d -R
    Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first. 
-d -RR
    Reattach a session and if necessary detach or create it. Use the first session if more than one session is available. 
-D -r
    Reattach a session. If necessary detach and logout remotely first. 
-D -R
    Attach here and now. In detail this means: If a session is running, then reattach. If necessary detach and logout remotely first. If it was not running create it and notify the user. This is the author's favorite. 
-D -RR
    Attach here and now. Whatever that means, just do it. 

Note: It is a good idea to check the status of your sessions with screen -list before using this option.
```

Comment: Thanks. But ps waux | grep screen does not show the screen session. screen -D is also stuck.

Comment: Have you tried "screen -D -RR <sessionname>" ?

Comment: "screen -D -RR <sessionname>" worked when "screen -D -RR" didn't, even when I had only one screen session in "screen -ls". Thanks!